# JavaScript form validation with else if

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement

I have been creating JavaScript validation for a form though run into difficulties. There are currently two parts to parts at (at the moment) for JavaSCript to check (email and sms). THe script is only running email and not checking sms at all when should be checking both together. If both are fine then return true. Any ideas?

```
function validateForm() {
    var emailBoxChecked = document.getElementById("checkemail").checked
    var emailBoxChecked = document.getElementById("checksms").checked
    var errordiv = document.getElementById('error');
    var errorsms = document.getElementById('errorsms');
        /*postOptOutSix.checked = false;
        postOptOutForever.checked = false*/
    // Conditions
    if (document.getElementById("emailradios") ==null && document.getElementById("emailforever") ==null) {
        if (document.getElementById("smsforever") ==null && document.getElementById("smsforever") ==null) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (document.getElementById("checksms").checked ==false && document.getElementById("smsOptOutSix").checked ==false && document.getElementById("smsOptOutForever").checked ==false) {  
            errordiv.innerHTML += "<p id='errorp' style='color:red;'>*SMS - Please either opt-in post or select either of the options.'";
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("checkemail").checked ==false && document.getElementById("emailOptOutSix").checked ==false && document.getElementById("emailOptOutForever").checked ==false) {  
        errorsms.innerHTML += "<p id='errorp' style='color:red;'>*Email - Please either opt-in post or select either of the options.'";
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You dont need to add ==null  also you can use the "!" instead of ==false

Comment: I have a feeling this is due to a logic error: your check that includes `checksms` will only run if `document.getElementById("emailradios") ==null && document.getElementById("emailforever") ==null`. If those elements are present in the DOM, you'll skip down to your `else if` below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to separate the 2 conditions checks, and only then check if some failed or not before returning.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function validateForm () {
    var errors = [];
    // Empty any previous errors
    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";

    // Check for SMS
    if (!document.getElementById("checksms").checked && 
        !document.getElementById("smsOptOutSix").checked && 
        !document.getElementById("smsOptOutForever").checked) {
        // add the SMS error to the array
        errors.push("<p id='errorp' style='color:red;'>*SMS - Please either opt-in post or select either of the options.'");
    }

    // Check for Email
    if (!document.getElementById("checkemail").checked && 
        !document.getElementById("emailOptOutSix").checked && 
        !document.getElementById("emailOptOutForever").checked) {  
        // add the Email error to the array
        errors.push("<p id='errorp' style='color:red;'>*Email - Please either opt-in post or select either of the options.'");
    }

    // Display the error(s) if any
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        errors.forEach(function (err) {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML += err;
        });
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Also, I noticed that `id='errorp'` is there twice. Rename one of them.

Comment: I have renamed one of them to id='errorq' for testing purposes. This is actually working. The text keeps repeating though when keep pressing the submit. I tried to hide a div and show it instead. This works but includes the word 'block' as well. How can I avoid that? (maybe for a generic message alternative).

`code`errors.push(errorDiv.style.display = 'block');`code`

Comment: Hey @shimmy, just add `document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "";` at the beginning of the function to clear previous error messages. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var emailBoxChecked = document.getElementById("checkemail").checked
var emailBoxChecked = document.getElementById("checksms").checked
```

You are setting the same variable from different elements.  Shouldn't it be like this?

```
var emailBoxChecked = document.getElementById("checkemail").checked
var smsBoxChecked = document.getElementById("checksms").checked
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML `required` and `pattern` attributes along with `inputElement.checkValidity()` which returns `true` or `false`. You could look on `keyup`, for example, to make sure all inputs are valid and if so enable the submit button and if not disable it.